# Few questions about OpenWRT and CCMP/TKIP key management

Tags: router, daemon

I don't know if I should post this question on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) but I think I'm doing well by posting it here (if I'm not doing well, correct me). I have questions about wpa key management and OpenWRT:

**1. What is hostapd and wpad daemons?**

**2. What manages CCMP/TKIP keys (Group Key generation, keys exchanging etc.)? OpenWRT or above daemons?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once upon a time, when you wanted to do WPA or WPA2 on Linux, `wpa_supplicant` was the Supplicant (client) you used, and `hostapd` was the Authenticator (AP/server side).

OpenWrt seems to have replaced both of those pieces with `wpad`, and if you don't need "WPA2 Enterprise" (real 802.1X) support — that is, if you just need to do WPA2 Personal (a.k.a. "WPA2 PSK") — you can use `wpad-mini`.

Yes, `hostapd` or `wpad` (whichever one you're using) is the AP-side process that keeps track of WPA2 key generation/negotiations, group key rotation, etc.

Basically, anything sent over the air in an `eapol` or `eapol-key` frame is going to/from whichever of those two daemons you're running.